# ReactSearchBox Not Loading Array From Fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I have a component that uses the [ReactSearchBox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-search-box). This component can be loaded with a list of options so that as users start typing, the search box makes suggestions.

Searchable items are loaded via an array with key/value pairs. To illustrate my problem, I've created two. Topics, which is working, is initialized with hard coded values, and nameKeysArr, which isn't, is part of the state and gets filled by a fetch in componentsDidMount from the API.

The code looks like this:

```
export class Home extends Component {
  topics = [
       {
         key: 'cei_2',
         value: 'CEI'
       }
     ]

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state={
      nameKeysArr: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url = `topics/gettopickeys`
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if(!response.ok) {throw Error(response.statusText);}
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => {this.setState({nameKeysArr: data})})
      .catch(err => console.log(err));    
  }

  render () {
    let keyArr = this.state.nameKeysArr; //WHEN I DO THIS, IT DOES NOT WORK
    keyArr = topics; //THIS IS WORKING   //WHEN I DO THIS, IT DOES WORK
    return (
      <div>
          <ReactSearchBox data={keyArr} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The search box is not displaying the searchable options when called via the fetch and added to the state. I would expect `setState` to re-render with the namesKeyArr values , but the searchbox is only displaying values if they're hard-coded, which will not work.

In case there's doubt that the namesKeyArr isn't formatted the same, here's a sample output from the console:

```
0: Object { key: "CEI", value: "CEI" }  ​
1: Object { key: "CEI_1", value: "Current Execution Index" }
2: Object { key: "Control Account", value: "Control Account" }
3: Object { key: "QBD", value: "QBD" }
4: Object { key: "QBD_1", value: "Quantifiable Backup Data" }
5: Object { key: "Rolling Wave", value: "Rolling Wave" }
```

And here's the topics array:

```
0: Object { key: "cei", value: "Current Execution Index" }
1: Object { key: "cei_1", value: "CEI" }
2: Object { key: "control account", value: "Control Account" }
3: Object { key: "qbd", value: "Quantifiable Backup Data" }
4: Object { key: "qbd_1", value: "QBD" }
5: Object { key: "rolling wave", value: "Rolling Wave" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your data in `fetch`, you are loading your component. First you have to wait for the `api` to `fetch` the data

```
export class Home extends Component {
  topics = [
    {
      key: "cei_2",
      value: "CEI"
    }
  ];

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      nameKeysArr: [],
      isDataLoad: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url = `topics/gettopickeys`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ nameKeysArr: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), isDataLoad: true });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    let keyArr = this.state.nameKeysArr; //WHEN I DO THIS, IT DOES NOT WORK
    keyArr = topics; //THIS IS WORKING   //WHEN I DO THIS, IT DOES WORK
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isDataLoad ? <ReactSearchBox data={keyArr} /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```